# retrieve data after indexing a mysql table

Tags: solr

Even after indexing a mysql table,in solr am not able to retrieve data after querying like

http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=slno:5

My data-config.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
                  driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lbs"
                  user="user"
                  password="password"/>

    <document name="lbs">
        <entity name="radar_places"
                  query="select * from radar_places"

           deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM radar_places WHERE slno='${dataimporter.delta.slno}'"
  deltaQuery="SELECT slno FROM radar_places WHERE modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'" >
            <field column="slno" name="slno" />
            <field column="place_id" name="place_id" />
            <field column="name" name="name" />
            <field column="geo_rss_point" name="geo_rss_point" />
        <field column="url" name="url" />
        <field column="location_id" name="location_id" />
        <field column="time" name="time" /> 
       </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

In the browser I had used

http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import

Later when I checked status of command http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport/

I got this

```
<response>
−
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">1</int>
</lst>
−
<lst name="initArgs">
−
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<str name="status">idle</str>
<str name="importResponse"/>
−
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">1151</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2010-02-21 07:53:14</str>
−
<str name="">
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
</str>
<str name="Committed">2010-02-21 07:53:24</str>
<str name="Optimized">2010-02-21 07:53:24</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Failed">1151</str>
<str name="Time taken ">0:0:10.56</str>
</lst>
−
<str name="WARNING">
This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future.
</str>
</response>
```

1)Is this has to do anything with `<str name="Total Documents Failed">1151</str>`

Am not able to figure out whats going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that the data import configuration matches your Solr document schema?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Your output suggests that SQL query worked properly as 1151 rows were fetched. Most likely the mapping between output of query didn't match your document schema. For example required field was missing or misspelled.

Comment: Yes,you are right.Field types in my schema.xml didn't map with mysql data types.But now when i make change to schema and restart solr its giving HTTP 404 . I just changed field type string to int and textgen to date in my schema(which is required).

Comment: I got it working now .
there was mapping mistake wrt datatype 
Thank you for guiding.